# SceneKit camera shows extra space when it should not

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

### Update

I have uploaded the project to [GitHub](https://github.com/morganwilde/StackOverflowQuestionDemo) for easy replication of the problem.

### Question

I have a test scene, where I want to position an object (a `SCNBox` in this case) to be as wide as the screen. Here's the entirety of the code.

```
let scene = SCNScene()
let rootNode = scene.rootNode

// Box
let boxGeometry = SCNBox(width: 1, height: 1, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0)
let boxMaterial = SCNMaterial()
boxMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.redColor()
boxGeometry.firstMaterial = boxMaterial
let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: boxGeometry)
boxNode.position = SCNVector3(
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    z: -1)
rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)

// Camera
let camera = SCNCamera()
camera.zNear = 0
let cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    z: 0)
cameraNode.camera = camera
rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
```

But this doesn't produce exactly what I would expect - 100% width coverage. As the screenshot below indicates, there's about 2.5% of white space total on the sides. Why? And how do I need to adjust my camera/box to achieve full coverage of the screens width?

[image: Problem]

Comment: How do you actually set the box's size? Is this all the code you use?

Comment: That's how I set it, it's all there in the code section of my question. Are you having trouble reproducing my result?

Comment: So you do not actually use the screen size to set the box's size?

Comment: Correct, because that's how scenekit works?

Comment: But if you want to make it fill the screen, why don't you use the screen's size for that?

Comment: Are you familiar with how coordinates work in OpenGL? I'm not sure this line of questioning is relevant to the question.

Comment: Not quite, I know how SceneKit works though. And if you want the box to exactly fill the screen then let me know and I'll provide you with an answer. That's all I want to know ;)

Comment: I want to find out why the current position of the camera and the size of the box are producing such a result and how do I adjust it to make it fill the screen either in terms of it's height or width.

Comment: @LinusG. I was hoping to see your answer :)

Comment: Ok, can you upload your project to github or something because when I use the code you provided I don't see anything actually.

Comment: @LinusG. I've updated the question with a link to the repository on github. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a quick visual representation of what your code does (viewed from the Top):

1) Create a 2x2x2 cube at (0,0,0)

[image: Create Cube]

2) Move the cube to (0,0,-1)

[image: Move the Cube]

3) Add Camera at (0,0,0)

[image: Add camera]

As you can see, the Camera intersects with the cube. It's an unpredictable behavior, and it can intersect, fight on Z, or simply look inside.

In your question you used a 1x1x1 box. Here's what it looks like:

[image: 1x1x1 box]

As you can see, the box *should* fill the view. But that's because I used a standard camera (36mm, or around 50° xfov). By moving around your scene, I realized you have a really large FOV, meaning your scene looks exactly like this:

[image: Large FOV]

Or, if we zoom in:

[image: Zoomed]

Here we go! So how do we fix this? By increasing the FOV. In our case, the angle is 90. But you can find it again with simple trigonometry.

[image: Hell yeah math!]

And now the box completely fills the viewport!

Comment: Thanks so much! This answer explains everything I was puzzled about.

Comment: No problem, let me know if you need any other explaination.

Comment: This is a bit off-topic, but what do you do to know so much about SceneKit?

Comment: I'm just very interested by it! I'm not much of an OpenGL guy and Unity is overkill for me. Also, I love Objective-C so I decided to play as much as I can with Scenekit!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so you have two options.

1. you can kind of cheat, it will be easy but not really convenient

   - therefore increase the size of the box randomly or move it closer to the camera
2. make it the way it should be which would make it adaptive, will be harder though

   - therefore have a look at `.projectPoint()` and `.unprojectPoint()` *[as I have trouble figuring out I can not give you any code, you might try your luck]*

Hope that helps :)

**EDIT**
FYI - I do not think that your problem relates to the camera, if you set the size of the box to `0.5` instead of `1` then it actually is smaller which shows that it is no camera-based bug. 
Also, if you run the application on a device other than the iPhone 6+, you will see that the box *does* fill the screen at least on the right side.

Comment: Thanks, `projectPoint()` is something I haven't used before, but I still have to see if it leads to a solution.

Comment: `projectPoint()` (as far as I know) is to translate the 3D-coordinate system into a 2D one while `unprojectPoint()` does the opposite.